# Android Gradle sync failed issue Android Studio 3.1.4 & gradle 4.4

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Gradle sync ended up with the following errors

```
org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.4/gradle-3.1.4.pom'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:96)
```

AND

```
org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.4/gradle-3.1.4.pom'.
```

Kindly help

[image]

Comment: Manually, try to download the links and see if they're downloadable by your ip. If not, check AS proxy settings. It also happens for those who their IPs are blocked.

Comment: Thanks @Mohsen setting proxy details in gradle.properties file solved my problem

Comment: I'm also getting this error and I'm not using any proxy. I tried manually downloading and this link "https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.4/gradle-3.1.4.pom" returned json object with 404 error. Howver this link "https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.4/gradle-3.1.4.pom" I was abble to download the pom file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with my proxy server,I got the proxy details through this
   `chrome://net-internals/#proxy`

and putting these lines inside gradle.properties file solved my problem

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost= hostname or IP
systemProp.http.proxyPort=
systemProp.http.proxyUser=username
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost

systemProp.https.proxyHost=hostname or IP
systemProp.https.proxyPort=
systemProp.https.proxyUser=username
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost '
```